# Error in download CSV file

Tags: csv, download, inputstream, outputstream

When i add data in my application, it gets saved in CSV file. I have one more option to download the same CSV file. But it given error.
My code is:

```
String csvPath = Utility.getTestCSVFilePath();

        response.setContentType("application/x-download");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +test.getTestName()+".csv"+ "\"");

        PrintWriter responseOut = null;

        try {
            responseOut = response.getWriter();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(csvPath);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseOut.write("Some error has occurred while preparing the file for download.");
        }
```

When i debug the code, it gives error in the line:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

Whats the problem, please help.

Comment: try moving this line responseOut = response.getWriter(); after inputStream.close(); and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving this line
 `responseOut = response.getWriter();`

after

`inputStream.close();` and see if it works